# Какой алгоритм использовать для поиска данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть к примеру список запчастей кроссы я могу

1. создать базу и залить туда все запчасти и по базе делать поиск.
2. добавить данные в бинарный файл и использовать бинарные данные для поиска.

Подскажите мне пожалуйста.
Что быстрее бинарные данные или sql ?

Comment: Так ведь смотря *как* добавить и как делать поиск... База данных — тоже данные в бинарном файле :)

Comment: Если индексы в базе данных настроены правильно, то база данных, скорее всего, быстрее, поскольку там поиск по хеш-таблице (быстрее бинарного).

Comment: База - гораздо более универсальный и переносимый способ. Но вообще без подробностей тут сложно что-то советовать.

Comment: @Chorkov Бинарные данные и бинарный поиск вообще говоря никак не связаны ))  Ну, кроме слова "бинарный" в названии. Какой конкретно у автора будет поиск из вопроса непонятно. Ничто не мешает и хэш-таблицы ему сделать.

Comment: если структура данных хорошо известна, то хороший программист всегда сделает более быстрый поиск, другое дело, сколько на это пойдет времени. База данных - удобная штука, которая почти сразу может дать достаточно приемлемую скорость с минимальными затратами. Так что я бы начал с простой базы, например, sqlite, а потом, если скорости не будет хватать и будет потребность - переписать на своих структурах. те же данные можно и дальше хранить в базе, просто в памяти хранить свои хитрые индексы. Но если нужно.